# XSLT filitering for both begin with and followed by characters

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I am working in project where I am given a list of allowed characters, and required to remove the unwanted characters. I have the following done, but I felt it is cumbersome and than it should be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:variable name="follow">0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ?abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-&apos;.,/@&amp;()!+</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="start">0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ?abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="contains($start, substring(normalize-space(/Author/Name/FirstName),1,1)) and 
                    string-length(substring(normalize-space(/Author/Name/FirstName),1,1)) > 0 and
                    string-length(translate(substring(normalize-space(/Author/Name/FirstName),2),translate(substring(normalize-space(/Author/Name/FirstName),2),$follow,''),'')) &gt; 0">
                        <div>
                            <xsl:value-of select="translate(substring(normalize-space(/Author/Name/FirstName),1),
                            translate(substring(normalize-space(/Author/Name/FirstName),1),$follow,''),'')" />
                        </div>    
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>NULL</xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Testing the start condition I have added three checks. The contains check returns true for empty string case, and thus I have added string length condition in order to return a NULL for empty string case.

```
FirstName>?    #</FirstName>//NULL
<FirstName></FirstName>//NULL
<FirstName>   ??</FirstName>//??
<LastName>?t*#</LastName>//?t
```

My XML for testing is below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Author>
    <Name>
        <FirstName>xxx</FirstName>
    </Name>
</Author>
```

I may have missed any edge cases, my question is is there a better way to solving this XSLT filtering task where starting and consecutive characters are conditional?

**EDIT**
Reading michael.hor257k comment made me question my approach and understand my requirement more. There is [Cybersource](https://support.cybersource.com/s/article/What-additional-field-validation-was-added-in-January-2013) page where it specifies allowed characters when making requests to their api. My target is to clean unwanted characters and make sure that field begin and followed by characters meets the specs given on the website. Take Ship-To Company name as example.
I am using XSLT 1.0 with java Transformer class

Comment: Which XSLT processor, which XSLT version do you use? Java suggests you could use Saxon with XSLT 2 or 3 where regular expression support is part of XPath 2 and later with functions like `matches` or `replace` and (XPath 3.1) `analyze-string` plus XSLT (with `xsl:analyze-string`). Even with Xalan I think there is EXSLT or the ability to call into Java to make use of regular expressions.

Comment: Your task is not entirely clear. You say you are "required to remove the unwanted characters". Suppose the 1st character is illegal and you remove it. Thus the 2nd character becomes 1st. So then you need to test it for being a legal starting character too, do you not? And so on, until you either find a legal one or run out. I don't fully follow your code, but it seems to be doing something else.

Comment: P.S. My approach would be to start by removing all characters that are not allowed to be 1st from the entire string. Then the first character of the resulting string (if there is a resulting string) becomes the first character of the final string. Next we remove the characters before the chosen starting character from the original string  and filter the rest for legal following  characters. Again, this is if the task is as described.

Comment: michael.hor257k, I have added an edit to my first inquiry. The scenario you have provided make sense. I have edited the question. I have no information what is not allowed. I wanted to work with what is allowed characters to complete the task. I would appreciate if you give me a sketch of what actual implementation can be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following **simplified** example:

**XML**

```
<input>
    <item>alpha</item>
    <item>-alpha</item>
    <item>alp§ha</item>
    <item>---al§pha§</item>
    <item>§al-pha</item>
</input>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="allowed-start-chars">abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="allowed-follow-chars">abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/input">
    <output>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item">
    <!-- find the first character eligible to be starting character -->
    <xsl:variable name="start-chars" select="translate(., translate(., $allowed-start-chars, ''), '')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="start-char" select="substring($start-chars, 1, 1)"/>
    <!-- get text after the chosen starting character -->
    <xsl:variable name="tail" select="substring-after(., $start-char)"/>
    <result original="{.}">
        <xsl:value-of select="$start-char"/>
        <!-- remove unwanted characters from tail -->
        <xsl:value-of select="translate($tail, translate($tail, $allowed-follow-chars, ''), '')"/>
    </result>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
   <result original="alpha">alpha</result>
   <result original="-alpha">alpha</result>
   <result original="alp§ha">alpha</result>
   <result original="---al§pha§">alpha</result>
   <result original="§al-pha">al-pha</result>
</output>
```

You might want to add a test for the case where all characters turn out to be illegal - although that seems highly unlikely.

---

### Added:

If all you want is to test the input for being valid, then you could do:

```
<xsl:template match="item">
    <!-- test the first character -->
    <xsl:variable name="valid-start-char" select="contains($allowed-start-chars, substring(., 1, 1))"/>
    <!-- test following characters  -->
    <xsl:variable name="invalid-follow-chars" select="translate(substring(., 2), $allowed-follow-chars, '')"/>
    <result original="{.}">
       <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$valid-start-char and not($invalid-follow-chars)">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>NULL</xsl:otherwise>
       </xsl:choose>
    </result>
</xsl:template>
```

to get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
    <result original="alpha">alpha</result>
    <result original="-alpha">NULL</result>
    <result original="alp§ha">NULL</result>
    <result original="---al§pha§">NULL</result>
    <result original="§al-pha">NULL</result>
</output>
```

Comment: I am new to XSLT and trying to figure out how to use apply-template you provided and  send conditional values. If valid show the filtered output, and if not show NULL to result element. Similar to to the original  xslt I have posted.

Comment: I am afraid I do not follow. If the input is valid, then there is no need to filter it.

Comment: if valid input I want to display <result original="abc">abc</result>, and if not valid then I wanted to display <result orginal="??">NULL</result>

Comment: That's very different from the original task. I have added this to my answer, but you should have posted this as a separate question.

Comment: apologies for the confusion. Your original approach is what I am looking, but my only question was  when all characters are turns out illegal, it would result <result ../>. I wanted to add choose/when or some sort of xslt condition to your original answer so that when all characters are illegal I would return NULL. I have accepted your answer